# Cant Generate Easy-Extends of SonataUserBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-user-bundle

i am at the ending stage of installing SonataUserBundle,
When i run,
`app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataUserBundle -d src --dest=src`
i get

> [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
>     Class 'Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User' does not exist

I followed everything according to [This Doc](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html)

Any idea how to get through it?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove/comment SonataUserBundle new instanse creation in AppKernel.php and its config in app/config/config.yml (I have not try it myself),

or you can in SonataUserBundle define existing classes (\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser etc) and edit config after succesful extending (it's my method, maybe it is not perfect).